# Track Gmail email opens on Salesforce

Tags: email, gmail, salesforce

When sending an email to a Saleforce contact using Gmail I would like to track the opening of that email and send it back to Salesforce.
Any ideas on how to do that ? The only way I found is to send the email from Salesforce.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome extension [Email Tracker for Gmail - Mailtrack](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-tracker-for-gmail-m/ndnaehgpjlnokgebbaldlmgkapkpjkkb?hl=en) seems to have the functionality that you are looking for in their Pro (paid) version. It will tell you when your email has been read and it has an integration to Salesforce.

[image: Mailtrack]

There are probably other third-party applications that provide similar functionality. For the record, I am not affiliated with them in any way.